# Cannot RDP to an instance of virtual machine scale set of a Service Fabric cluster in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-resource-manager, rdp, windowsdomainaccount

I have created a Service Fabric cluster by using the well-known [azure-quickstart-templates/service-fabric-secure-cluster-5-node-1-nodetype](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/service-fabric-secure-cluster-5-node-1-nodetype) template.

During the deployment I have specified the **adminUsername** and **adminPassword** strings as the [ARM template parameters](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/service-fabric-secure-cluster-5-node-1-nodetype/azuredeploy.parameters.json). I have just used 2 long strings of random characters and written them down for later.

The deployment has succeeded and I can for example open the SF cluster explorer webpage with the famous green circles.

When I try to connect to one of the nodes of the VMSS though, in order to check my SF application logs, the RDP connection is being refused:

[image: rdp screenshot]

I use the Loader public IP address for the RDP connection and have verified that there is an LB rule for that:

[image: lb screenshot]

When I enter the **adminUsername** and **adminPassword** strings I had specified during the ARM template deployment, the RDP connection prepends the domain of my corporate notebook.

So I have tried prepending the LB public ip address followed by a backslash in front of the **adminUsername**, but that does not work either.

Also I have tried **.\adminUsername** (takes my corporates notebook's domain which is wrong) and **\adminUsername**  and **nt1vm_1\adminUsername** (still does not connect):

[image: screenshot rdp]

How can I please RDP-connect to the VMSS instances of my SF cluster?

I have also created the [Github issue #7684](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/issues/7684) for my problem.

**UPDATE:**

Cannot connect with Microsoft Remote Desktop for mac OS either:

[image: mac screenshot]

**UPDATE 2:**

Apologies for oversimplifying my problem description -

I have actually not written the RDP credentials to paper, but generated and saved them in a Key Vault, then outputted them as the pipeline variables (I know, not so secure...) and passed them to the SF template:

[image: kv screenshot]

So this is not the issue of me writing down wrong credentials. And this YAML file is used by 5 pipelines, to fill 5 different RGs (with CosmosDb, Key Vault, SF) - all having the above RDP connection problem.

**UPDATE 3:**

Because I have 3 nodes in the SF cluster, I have tried using **nt1vm_0\username**, **nt1vm_1\username**, **nt1vm_2\username** and even **nt1vm\username** as username at the RDP dialog, but alas that does not work:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried simply `\adminUsername` (without the `.`)?

Comment: I did that too - unfortunately still no connection

Comment: "I have just used 2 long strings of random characters and written them down for later" - is this issue reproducible?  Or is there a chance that the credentials could be incorrect?

Comment: Actually, in the Azure pipeline before deploying the SF cluster, I have [deployed a Key Vault, with 2 secrets](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-key-vault-secret-create) generated by `uniqueString()` plus some capital letters and digits to satisfy the password complexity. And I have passed them as pipeline vars for the SF template. So this is not the issue and apologies for simplifying my description. I did not write them down on paper, but instead saved as 2 secrets in the KV before deploying SF.

Comment: Concerning the statement "outputted them as the pipeline variables ... and passed them to the SF template" -- does that mean you are using Azure DevOps release pipelines to deploy? The reason I ask is because I got burned by using PowerShell in a pipeline and consumed a variable with a password using `"$(sfcPassword)"`. The resolved variable contained a '$' within the value which was then treated as a PowerShell variable within the password string.

Comment: did you try  `nt1vm_0\adminUsername` on port 3389? (you said `nt1vm_1\adminUsername` )

Comment: Thanks for replying (upvoted), but this does not work - please see the Update 3

Comment: did you try doing a [password resethttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/scripts/service-fabric-powershell-change-rdp-user-and-pw]() on the scaleset to see if the credentials may have been changed somehow?

Comment: @LoekD this is a good workaround too! Please submit as answer and I will accept :-)

Comment: great, glad you worked it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing a [password reset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/scripts/service-fabric-powershell-change-rdp-user-and-pw) on the scaleset to see if the credentials may have been changed somehow.

```
Login-AzAccount
Get-AzSubscription
Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId 'yourSubscriptionID'

$nodeTypeName = 'nt1vm'
$resourceGroup = 'sfclustertutorialgroup'
$publicConfig = @{'UserName' = 'newuser'}
$privateConfig = @{'Password' = 'PasSwo0rd$#!'}
$extName = 'VMAccessAgent'
$publisher = 'Microsoft.Compute'
$node = Get-AzVmss -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -VMScaleSetName $nodeTypeName
$node = Add-AzVmssExtension -VirtualMachineScaleSet $node -Name $extName -Publisher $publisher -Setting $publicConfig -ProtectedSetting $privateConfig -Type $extName -TypeHandlerVersion '2.0' -AutoUpgradeMinorVersion $true

Update-AzVmss -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $nodeTypeName -VirtualMachineScaleSet $node
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my own answer, maybe it will help someone too -

It seems to be a bug in SF Cluster (we use Service Fabric version 7.1.417.9590) ARM template deployment.

We have noticed, that RDP worked if you "Reimage" all instances in the VMSS:

[image: vmss instances]

Without the reimaging the RDP connection was refused as if the credentials were wrong.

In our Azure pipeline the RDP credentials were generated by the following code in the Key Vault ARM template (the capital letters and digits to satisfy password complexity requirements + a unique string based on deployment name):

```
"variables": {
    "RdpUsername": "[concat('ABC123', uniqueString(deployment().name, 'RdpUsername'))]",
    "RdpPassword": "[concat('ABC123', uniqueString(deployment().name, 'RdpPassword'))]"
},
"outputs": {
    "RdpUsername": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "[variables('RdpUsername')]"
    },
    "RdpPassword": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "[variables('RdpPassword')]"
    },
    "keyvaultId": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', variables('keyvaultName'))]"
    }
},
```

The `uniqueString` is based on deployment name and thus is changed with each pipeline deployment (that is why there are different secret versions in the screenshot below):

[image: key vault]

Then the above secrets where passed to the pipeline task deploying SF cluster:

```
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  displayName: 'Deploy SF cluster'
  inputs:
    deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
    subscriptionId: '${{ parameters.SubscriptionId }}'
    azureResourceManagerConnection: '${{ parameters.ArmConnection }}'
    action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
    resourceGroupName: '${{ parameters.ResourceGroupName }}'
    location: '${{ parameters.ResourceLocation }}'
    templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
    csmFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/pipelines/templates/sfcluster.json'
    csmParametersFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/pipelines/templates/sfcluster-params.json'
    overrideParameters: '-rdpUsername $(RdpUsername) -rdpPassword $(RdpPassword) -certificateThumbprint $(Thumbprint) -sourceVaultResourceId $(KeyvaultId) -certificateUrlValue $(SecretId)' 
    deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
```

Because there seems to be a bug, the RDP connection still required the older pair of the RDP credentials.

So our workaround is to change the RDP credentials to a more stable string, based on the RG name:

```
"variables": {
    "RdpUsername": "[concat('Ccg1', uniqueString(resourceGroup().name, 'RdpUsername'))]",
    "RdpPassword": "[concat('Ccg2', uniqueString(resourceGroup().name, 'RdpPassword'))]"
},
```

And now RDP connections work (with username **nt1vm_0\RdpUsername** etc.):

[image: rdp screenshot]